# How to overcome this 2D -Transpose Matrix Index Out of Bound Exception in C# program

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

As you can see this is 2D transpose of matrix program, when executing this program it throws an index out of bound exception when it reached in some lines of code. Code raising exception is mentioned below.

**C# Program**

````
static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Console.Write("No of Rows entered = ");
                    int r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
                    Console.Write("No of Columns entered = ");
                    int c= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    int[,] arr1 = new int[r, c];
                    int[,] arr2 = new int[r, c];
                    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("[{0}],[{1}] : ", i, j+" ");
                            arr1[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Matrix before Transpose:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
                            Console.Write("{0}", arr1[i, j]+" ");
                    }
```
    
**When it execute this lines of code it shows exception**
            
```
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
                {
                    arr2[j, i] = arr1[i, j];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Matrix after Transpose: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}", arr2[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
```
[Image of Exception appear while executing the program][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rNCg.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of r and c should be changed in the definition of arr2:

```
int[,] arr2 = new int[c, r];
```

In the last for-loop, r and c should also be changed from position:

```
Console.WriteLine("Matrix after Transpose: ");
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}", arr2[i, j]);
    }
}
```